# Как найти и заменить в строке несколько значений?

Tags: php

Возникла нужда писать excel-функции. Но, так как самих функций писать нужно много то я решил перебирать и выводить их через цикл в php, и уже готовые вставлять в excel-файл. Прилагаю фото интерфейса для более детального ознакомления:

[image: Интерфейс]
Далее мне нужно было написать код который принимал бы переменые и значения, находил и менял их в строке. Я попробовал так...

```
if (isset($_POST['variable1'])) {
    $variables = array(
        $_POST['variable1'] => $_POST['value1'],
        $_POST['variable2'] => $_POST['value2'],
        $_POST['variable3'] => $_POST['value3'],
        $_POST['variable4'] => $_POST['value4'],
    );
}

function calculate($fx, $cikle, $variables) {
    for ($x=0; $x<$cikle; $x++) {
        $count = count($variables);
        for ($x=0; $x<=$count; $x++) {
            //    str_ireplace(что ищем, на что меняем, где ищем);
            $v = $variables[$x];
            $fx = str_ireplace(key($v), $variables[$x], $fx);
        }
        $res .= '<tr><td>'.$fx.'</td></tr>';
    }
    return $res;
}
```

И у меня не получилось.

Comment: если у вас проблема с функцией `calculate`, то приведите пример того что подаете  на вход, и что хотите на выходе. скриншоты и post-данные мало помогут в решении.

Comment: @teran как видно на скрине у меня есть 4 переменых со значениями. Их я запихиваю в массив `$variables` и перебираю через функцию `str_ireplace()`. Но чтобы функция нашла и заменила несколько значений что я делаю это через цикл. Соответственно мне нужно проциклить столько раз, сколько у меня есть переменных. Нужно чтобы каждый цикл функция `str_ireplace()` искала в `$fx` имя ключа массива и меняла его на значение ключа массива.

Comment: повторюсь, приведите `print_r()` всех входных данных. и html код результирующей строки.

Comment: но `key($v)` вам точно в решении не поможет ничем

Comment: @teran По функции `key()` я пытаюсть "отловить" имя ключа. Так как мне нужно его использовать в качестве иголки которую я ищу в строке. А `print_r()` не выводит ничего так как после отправки запроса программа просто зациклилась.

Comment: чтобы ключи не отлавливать, используйте синтаксис `foreach( $variables as $k => $v)`. Чтобы ничего не закицлиось, при запуске функции выведите нужные данные, и напишите `return/die`. Циклиться у вас небось потому что не известно что вообще такое `$cikle`, во вложенном цикле тоже надо заменить `<=` на `<`.

Comment: @teran Проблемму зациклености решил. Вся загвоздка оказалась в моей невнимательности. Дело в том что я впихнул в один цикл со счетчиком `$x` другой цикл со счетчиком `$x`.

Comment: @teran `$cikle` - оно означает сколько раз должен отработать внешний цикл. На скрине видно что 10 раз. Но по поводу ключей то мне их как раз таки и нужно знать. Для этого я и использовал функцию `key()`.